# django-social-auth: logging in from a unit test client

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I use django-social-auth as my authentication mechanism and I need to test my app with logged in users. I'm trying:

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()
c.login(username='myfacebook@username.com", password='myfacebookpassword')
```

The user which is trying to login succeeds to login from a browser. The app is already allowed to access user's data.

Any ideas how to login from a unittest when using django-social-auth as the authentication mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: Social Auth recently integrated a way to easily test things like that. Please, have a look at http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/master/testing_tools.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django unit test; Login using python-social-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897225/django-unit-test-login-using-python-social-auth)

Answer (score 2):

Create a fixture with User instances

```
{
    "pk": 15,
    "model": "auth.user",
    "fields": {
        "username": "user",
        "first_name": "user",
        "last_name": "userov",
        "is_active": true,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "is_staff": false,
        "last_login": "2012-07-20 15:37:03",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": [],
        "password": "!",
        "email": "",
        "date_joined": "2012-07-18 13:29:53"
    }
}
```

Create a fixture with SocialAuthUser instances like this

```
{
    "pk": 7,
    "model": "social_auth.usersocialauth",
    "fields": {
        "uid": "1234567",
        "extra_data": "%some account social data%",
        "user": 15,
        "provider": "linkedin"
    }
}
```

So you will get the user, who has the same behavior as a real user and has all the social data you need.
Set the new password and then you can use the auth mechanism for log this user in:

```
...
user.set_password('password')
user.save()                    
logged_in = self.client.login(username='user', password='password')
```

and then just call the view with login required

```
self.client.get("some/url")
```

Don't forget, that `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` is needed, and `django.contrib.sessions` should be in your INTALLED_APPS tuple

Also, the advantage of using standard auth is that you don't need to make a server request for getting oauth tokens and so on.